# Quadratic Polynomial Solver C

Tags: c

Here is the code i made for a homework assignment, I followed a similar format from a previous lab to construct this code. The code compiles successfully and I am able to enter all coefficients but once that is done nothing more happens and the intergers are not plugged in to the equation.

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*Quadratic Polynomial Solver*/
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
int A,B,C,X; 
printf("Enter Coefficient A:");
scanf("%d",&A);
printf("Enter Coefficient B:");
scanf("%d",&B);
printf("Enter Coefficient C:");
scanf("%d",&C);
printf("Enter Variable X:");
scanf("%d",&X);
A * X * X + B * X + C;

return 0; 

}
```

Comment: How do you know? You have to print the result to be able to do anything with it

Comment: Also, `A * X * X + B * X + C;´ without assigning it to anything does nothing

Comment: You are evaluating the polynomial rather than solving it

Answer (score 4):

You need to save the result of your equation somehow and then compute it, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*Quadratic Polynomial Solver*/
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int A,B,C,X,R;
    printf("Enter Coefficient A:");
    scanf("%d",&A);
    printf("Enter Coefficient B:");
    scanf("%d",&B);
    printf("Enter Coefficient C:");
    scanf("%d",&C);
    printf("Enter Variable X:");
    scanf("%d",&X);
    R = A * X * X + B * X + C; // Save result to int R
    printf("Solution is %d",R); // Compute Result
    return 0; 

}
```

Here a new `int` variable of `R` (for result) is used to save the result of your equation and then it is printed with `printf`

Comment: When you say "computed", do you mean "printed"?

Comment: @dbush Yes, "computed" means communicated in some way. You could print it, save it to a file, or do 5000 other things with it. Printing is the particularly easiest way for demo purposes.

Comment: Here `R = A * X * X + B * X + C;` is where the value is *computed*. Here `printf("Solution is %d",R);` is where the value is *communicated*.

Answer (score 1):

you need to compute something and then print it

```
int foo = A * X * X + B * X + C;
printf("foo=%d\n", foo);
```